# afci protection for kitchen hood fan

Tags: afci

I'm wiring a new house and have installed a dedicated 15 amp circuit to the hood fan located over the range in the kitchen. Does this circuit need to be on a afci breaker?

Comment: Why are you putting the hood fan on a dedicated circuit? (Unless it's a monster aka massively oversized fan, *or* you have an AHJ that insists on dedicated circuits for every fixed kitchen appliance, there's no reason not to put it on a kitchen light circuit instead.)  Also, what NEC edition has your city or county adopted?

Comment: you nailed it with AHJ, the county has adopted 2017

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, this needs to be on an AFCI

All 15A and 20A, 120V kitchen outlets (not just receptacles, but lighting and fixed appliances too) have been required to be AFCI protected since the 2014 NEC.  (See 210.12(A) for the details -- it covers just about any sort of space you'll find within a dwelling unit proper.)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in a kitchen that has to be afci that I'm aware of is the dishwasher. The dishwasher has to be both GFCI and afci, or at least that's the code in my city.